# What makes metric spaces have balls always containing points other than its center, too?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $M$ be a metric space, $x\in M$, $\varepsilon>0$. What do we need from $M$ to guarantee
$$ \mathbb{B}(x,\varepsilon)\setminus\{x\} \neq\emptyset?$$

E.g., would it suffice to have $M$ be polish?

Comment: Isn't this just that $x$ is not an isolated point of $M$?

Comment: @MPW Yes, thank you. So, is there something weaker than $M$ being perfect implying $M$ to have no isolated points?

Comment: "No ball is a singleton" is equivalent to "there are no isolated points". If you're asking about a fixed $x$ and all $\varepsilon > 0$, it's "$x$ isn't an isolated point", as MPW said. Note that every finite metric space is polish, as is $\mathbb{Z}$ with the Euclidean metric, so polish doesn't prevent isolated points.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you! I was asking about all $x$ but I have the question already answered to my satisfaction. I would accept your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $x \in (M,d)$, there is some $r_x>0$ such that $\Bbb B(x,r_x)=\{x\}$ iff $x$ is an isolated point (i.e. $\{x\}$ is open).

So if you want this for all $x$, $M$ needs to be *crowded* (i.e. have no isolated points). Polish spaces can have isolated points, but a connected metric space will not have them, if it has more than one point of course. So if you want an easily quotable condition, just use "let $M$ be a crowded metric space" or a connected non-trivial metric space instead. Of course a space like $[0,1] \cup [2,3]$ we have disconnected crowded space, so the first condition is more to the point and exactly what you'd need.